# Positioning Image and Text in a button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image, button, text

I have a Button on my Form. I want to have an image on the left and text on the right like :

`Image Text`

But the problem is that image is not stretched here. I mean it does not fit the button.

So I tried to set the `BackGroundImage` Property instead of `Image` Property.

Now I get the Image stretched. But I cant get the proper Format. I mean now I cant get Image on the left and Text on the right.

Is there any other control which I can use instead of button to Overcome this problem?

Comment: Ever think about WPF. What you want is possible and very easy to do. It is also helpful if you tell us what platform your working on.

Comment: I am working on WinForms. I don't know XAML so I don't use WPF

Comment: Neither did I before I started. It has intellisense support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think using stretch will in any case.  How is it supposed to determine the border to stretch to?
With the imagealign set middleleft and the textalign set middleright I was able to make this button, it's 82X48.  The image I used is 52X39.  I used paint to resize the image.

[image]

Comment: It would determine the border based on the border of the button. The control knows its own border. But you're right, there's no property for this because it's not something people would ever want. No one resizes buttons at runtime. To get the effect, he'll have to draw it himself on an owner-drawn button.

Comment: But to leave room for the text there's no border there.

Comment: That's true, it could measure the text. You'd have to do so if you wanted to write a custom control. The method you'd want is [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

The button has a `TextImageRelation` property, set it to `ImageBeforeText`. Set the `Image` property with your image and there you go.

Comment: No It only works if image is set using the Image Property. It does not work if we set image using BackGroundImage Property.

Comment: If image is set using image property then image does not resize with change in the size of the form or bitton

Comment: This is the correct answer. @Vishal The `BackgroundImage` property isn't intended for use with `Button` controls. The only way to get an image that resizes itself with the button (why do you have a button that changes size randomly?) is to draw it yourself. There are overloads of the [`Graphics.DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx) method that allow you to specify a scale size.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method that may work out good is to put both an image and button inside a panel. This gives you the flexibility of text placement, image scaling and use anchor or dock options to size the controls with the panel and form. Not tested but sounds like it could work...

Answer (score 1):

If you used Button control  .. and you want to add image to it

Create New Button and do domething in it's properties

- **Image** : you can insert an image from anywhere (local or resource)
- **ImageAlign** : Set it to Middle Left
- **TextAlign** : Set it to Middle right

It tested on VB.NET 2005

Answer (score 1):

To change a button's image size, you can use the image property . Your image will be resized to you specific dimension

```
Button2.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\image.jpg").GetThumbnailImage(20, 20, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero)
```